# HTTP Error 500.19 - The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-500

Trying to run an ASP.NET MVC application on IIS on a brand new Windows 2019 server and this error occurs when trying to open it up in a browser:

[image]

The web.config file was copied along with the rest of the project files to the new server verbatim with no changes made. On the old server it works perfectly fine.

The error in the screenshot is not very helpful. Any ideas what could be wrong here? The app pool its running under is set to run under .net 4.0 and 32bit applications are set to true

Comment: Error 500.19 means an error in the web.config itself. Maybe something is not installed on the server but is on the dev machine? Like the IIS url rewrite module perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> HTTP Error 500.19 – Internal Server Error
>
> Error Code: 0x8007000d
>
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

**Cause**

This problem occurs because the ApplicationHost.config or Web.config file contains a malformed or unidentified XML element. IIS can't identify the XML elements of the modules that are not installed. For example, IIS URL Rewrite module.

**Resolution**

Use one of the following methods:

- Delete the malformed XML element from the ApplicationHost.config or
  Web.config file.
- Check the unidentified XML elements, and then    install the relevant
  IIS modules.

You can also refer to this [article](https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html) by Lex Li, I hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: "For example, IIS URL Rewrite module." this was the case for me